# Image Display in PHP

Tags: php, image

I want to display image through PHP. 
 When I put image in /var/www/ directory then it is working fine, I am giving full path.

But when I put image in some other directory (say home) then it is not displaying.

Comment: Please paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, servers have some kind of sandbox which prevent your code to access files outside of it for security reasons.
I encourage you to put all data you want your server to be able to access inside its folders (/var/www directory or subdirectories of it)

Comment: For the time being I am not worried about security. And my image data is in External Hard disk with large memory so can't copy that into /var/www/ folder. Any idea how to bypass that .....

Comment: Check it's not a file permission issue. Depending on the linux distro, the user running the webserver (asumming it's apache or something similar) is www-data or www-run, a user inside a group with the same name. Is that user or group allowed to read those files?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should really check your error logs as they will probably point you in the right direction.

Without more information, I'd have an educated guess that the Apache user does not have rights to the file and/or the containing directories.

You can change permissions using the chown and chmod commands in a shell.

EDIT: But don't allow access to any dir with sensitive data (e.g. your home directory) to the webserver!